# Fragment background gets transparent on focus of edittext?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, focus

Fragment background gets transparent when i tap on EditText, hint color change for a moment and background disappears sometimes and sometimes not and this happens almost every first time when EditText got focused.

**Transparent issue screenshot**
[image: check problem screenshot]

**Right screenshot**
[image]

**XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/app_small_padding">

    <com.q3.npf.comman.customfont.AppTextViewBold
        android:id="@+id/uldLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/uld"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorGreyDark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/default_txt_size" />

    <com.q3.npf.comman.customfont.AppEditText
        android:id="@+id/uldTxtViewDialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/uldLabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_small_padding_4dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/uldScanImg"
        android:background="@drawable/table_bg"
        android:hint="@string/scan_uld"
        android:maxLength="@integer/alternate_item_code"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/min_edittext_width"
        android:padding="@dimen/app_small_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorGreyDark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/default_txt_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/uldScanImg"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/scan_default_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/scan_default_icon_size"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_default_padding"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_default_padding"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:src="@drawable/scanbefore" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**parent layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frameLyt"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/blurBg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blur_bg2"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_small_padding"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_small_padding"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_rounded_bg"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/dialog_tab_lyt" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemCodeLyt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/app_default_padding"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <com.q3.npf.comman.customfont.AppTextViewBold
            android:id="@+id/scanItemLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/item"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_txt_size" />

        <com.q3.npf.comman.customfont.AppEditText
            android:id="@+id/itemCodeLabelTxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scanItemLabel"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_small_padding_4dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scanImg"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_bg"
            android:hint="@string/item_barcode"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/min_edittext_width"
            android:padding="@dimen/app_small_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorGreyDark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_txt_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/scanImg"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/scan_default_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/scan_default_icon_size"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scanItemLabel"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_default_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_default_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_small_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/scanbefore" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/uldLyt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/app_small_padding"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/scanUldRadioBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/scan_uld"
                android:textSize="@dimen/default_txt_size" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/generateUldRadioBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_small_padding"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/generate_uld"
                android:textSize="@dimen/default_txt_size" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <include
            layout="@layout/scan_uld_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/dialog_btn_lyt" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[issue][Original Dialog]

Comment: show your dialog xml

Comment: Actually this is normal fragment not dialog fragment, its  seeming  as a Dailog.

Comment: then show whatever that design

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have same issue.